# create df column based on matches between other column and a series.index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I've been trying to put together a working, simple implementation of this but my grip on pandas at this point in time is shaky. So suppose:

df1:
       `Field1
    0       a
    1       b
    2       c
    3       a
    4       c`

series1:
    `a  s1
    b  s2
    c  s3`

series1 contains all the unique values of df1.Field1 in its index. I would like to add a column to df1 which contains the values of series1 mapped according to corresponding value of df1.Field1 found in series1.index. So the result would be:

df1:
       `Field1   Field2
    0       a       s1
    1       b       s2
    2       c       s3
    3       a       s1
    4       c       s3`

Thankyou for your guidance.

Comment: Use `df1['Field2'] = df1['Field1'].map(series1) `

Comment: Ah....that works. I didn't recall that df1.['Field1'] returns a Series which is x in the pandas.Series.map documentation example: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.Series.map.html. 

Also the post u link as duplicate deals with dicts in particular. Thanks!